# Почему не работает ре-рендериг Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Есть переменная и функция. А так же html элемент.

```
  test = 1;
  countFunc() {
        this.test++;
    }

   <p (click)="countFunc()">{{test}}</p>
```

При клике на элемент, счетчик увеличивается на 1, и элемент сразу перерендеривается, показывая новое значение. Почему, когда я ставлю счетчик с помощью setInterval, элемент перестает ререндерится при том, что значение test увеличивается.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
      setInterval(() => {
          this.test++;
      }, 1000)
    }
```

Comment: У вас стратегия изменения какая, случайно не OnPush?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое поведение возможно, если у вас используется стратегия изменения OnPush

```
@Component({
   ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
```

Есть два варианта, как обновить данные:

1. Добавить принудительное изменение changeDetection через [changeDetectionRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

```js
export class AppComponent {
  test = 1;
  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.test++;

      // добавляем принудительный запуск changeDetection
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

2. Заменить setInterval на BehaviorSubject и [asyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

```js
export class AppComponent {
  private test = 1;
  test$ = new BehaviorSubject(1);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.test++;
      this.test$.next(this.test);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<p (click)="countFunc()">{{ test$ | async }}</p>
```

Также советую изучить как работает [OnPush](https://habr.com/ru/company/infopulse/blog/358860/) и про [changeDetectionStrategy](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy)

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался!